# TFS - xcopy not working with my TFS builds

Tags: templates, build, tfs, xcopy

I created a custom template for a TFS build that copies files from a Source folder to a Destination folder.

```
ForEach<String>
    InvokeProcess
        xcopy "C:SourceFolder\File1.doc" "C:DestinationFolder"

ForEach<String>
    InvokeProcess
        xcopy "C:SourceFolder\File2.doc" "C:DestinationFolder"
```

I can type the xcopy line into a command prompt and it works just fine, but for some reason not in TFS. I get no error. I have been stuck on this for a few days and now I'm just baffled. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Have you tried with Diagnostic Level Logging to see what's going on?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: When you do Queue A New Build, you can set the Verbosity. Change it to Diagnostic.

Comment: Have you run the XCopy command by hand as the same user the build service is running as? The permissions will probably be different

Comment: Also, unless the paths you gave are just bad examples, would using the built in CopyDirectory activity be better?

Comment: I gave TFSBuild admin permissions on my machine. Still no luck. I never thought to use CopyDirectory sense xcopy has an option for that.

Comment: No there is a team build activity already in the toolbox, called copydirectory. Could you use that instead of InvokeProcess on XCopy?

Comment: or did you notice your paths (if not examples) have no initial forward slash? C:DestinationFold should be C:\DestinationFold

Comment: I've actually just learned how to make custom activities through this tutorial: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx. This solved my problem and allowed me to do more of what I want. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fully qualify the path to xcopy. So the filename for invoke process should be "C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe"